# web scraping, get whole page using mechanize

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

my goal is to get all items from the page. i only get about the first 10 of the 25 though. i think it has something to do with the table, i think it's some type of widget?. i'm a beginner, still learning the basics.

```
import mechanize,time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

br = mechanize.Browser()  
br.set_handle_robots(False)  
br.addheaders = [("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13")]  

sign_in = br.open('https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/homepage.html?')  

br.select_form(name="signinWidget")  
br["username"] = 'spam' 
br["password"] = 'eggs'
logged_in = br.submit() 

orders_html = br.open("https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hz/inventory/ref=ag_invmgr_dnav_xx_?tbla_myitable=sort:{%22sortOrder%22%3A%22DESCENDING%22%2C%22sortedColumnId%22%3A%22date%22};search:;pagination:1;")

print('Login complete...')
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(orders_html,'html.parser')
partNums = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'mt-text-content mt-table-main'})

 print(partNums)

 for part in partNums:
  print(part.text)  

 print('Process Complete.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the HTML of a page by `br.response().read()`

```
orders_page = br.open("https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hz/inventory/ref=ag_invmgr_dnav_xx_?tbla_myitable=sort:{%22sortOrder%22%3A%22DESCENDING%22%2C%22sortedColumnId%22%3A%22date%22};search:;pagination:1;")  # loads page
orders_html = br.response().read()  # saves page source
```

Comment: Returned the same results.
I pulled the whole page and search for the last part number in the table and it's not there, it's like im only capturing the parts that are visible when the page is first loading, im not capturing the complete inventory list.